# ASP.NET: add postback to anchor

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my `javascript` file, I got an ajax to get all list and iterate these data and append `<a id='userID' class='btn'>Assign ID<>` to my list.

So, how do a add **postback** to these anchor and redirect it inside my method in the server. Below is my code but didn't work. When I click the achor button, it just redirect/refresh to the same page without doing any changes and didn't show the text.

```
<a id='uniqueID' class='btn assignID' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:__doPostBack('uniqueID','')'>Assign ID</a>

protected void Action_assignID(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // assign ID action
  Response.Write("Pass");
}
```

Comment: when you say it didn't work what exactly do you mean? It didn't compile? It didn't post to the server? or something else. please be specific.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, I update the question. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you add the href link to your `a` tag when you create it? then you do not need javascript `onclick` since it will just navigate to the `href`

Comment: @saf21 - I might be confused. You mentioned an AJAX call... are you generating these links in client code? In other words, using javascript?

Comment: @Josh, yup, I generate in client side because I'm using jquery datatables server side to call the list and append the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be changed your button to:

```
<a id='uniqueID' class='btn assignID' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('uniqueID','Assign ID')">Assign ID</a>
```

And it's a good idea to implement the IPostBackEventHandler interface in your codebehind as below:

```
public partial class WebForm : Page, IPostBackEventHandler
{

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {

            }
        }

        public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
        {
             // do somethings at here
        }
}
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

The `__doPostBack` method really doesn't do anything special except, well... perform a POST operation back to the same page with two specific form arguments.

The first parameter is the `__EVENTTARGET` and the second parameter is the `__EVENTARGUMENT`.

The magic all happens in ASP.Net where it automagically wires up your controls to event handlers, but since you are creating these entirely in JavaScript the server doesn't know that those controls exist.

However, you can manually grab these values and do something with them.

```
//Client Side JavaScript:
__doPostBack('my-event', '42');

//Code Behind
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        var target = Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
        var args = Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"];

        Target.Text = target; // 'my-event'
        Argument.Text = args; // '42'
    }
}
```